# Terraform: How to optionally assign a static private IP in aws_network_interface?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

How can I make a Terraform module defining an `aws_network_interface` resource to optionally assign a static private IP?

In a module, the resource is defined as

```
# Use this block if private_ips have been provided
resource "aws_network_interface" "management_interface" {
  count = "${var.count}"

  subnet_id = "${var.management_net}"
  # Workaround, see https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/12472
  private_ips = [ "${compact(list(element(split(",",var.private_ips), count.index)))}" ]

  tags {
    Name = "if-management"
  }
}
```

`private_ips` is either an empty string if dynamic private IP address is requested or a coma separated list (one element per instance) if a static private IP shall be assigned.

The module is called like this

```
module "dns" {
  count          = 2
  source         = "./modules/linux-system"
  […]
  private_ips    = "${cidrhost(var.management_subnet_cidr, 12)},${cidrhost(var.management_subnet_cidr, 13)}"
  […]
}
```

or

```
module "jumphost" {
  source         = "./modules/linux-system"
  […]
}
```

This solution does not seem to be idempotent: While the first `terraform apply` completes successfully, the next run causes

```
* module.jumphost.aws_network_interface.management_interface: 1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_network_interface.management_interface: Failure to unassign Private IPs: InvalidParameterValue: Value (10.128.16.139) for parameter privateIpAddress is invalid. The primary IP address of an interface cannot be unassigned.
        status code: 400, request id: 672b6d7d-6396-48bf-8bd0-77ce764709be
```

Anyone having an idea on how to do it right? Looks like something like Ansible's/Jinja2's `omit` is needed here.

Comment: Looks like this is not possible with Terraform version ≤ 0.11. Hashicorp introduces [new language features](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/terraform-0-12-conditional-operator-improvements) that help a lot here. Most important are probably the `null` value and a conditional operator (`?`) that can handle lists.